# Timing Python code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote below piece of code to understand multiprocessing(MP) and its possible speed gain versus the non-MP version. The two functions are almost the same except for highlighted places (sorry, didn't know a better way to highlight code regions).

The code tries to identify the indices of redundant entries in a list of arrays (here 1-D). The returned id-lists by the two functions are the same, but my question is about the time difference.

As you can see, I have tried to time a)map function, b)list extension and c)the whole while loop in both cases. The MP gives better speed up while in the `map` region but its `redun_ids.extend(...)` is slow compared to non-MP version. This in fact is forcing the overall speed gain by MP version to come down.

Is there any way I could rewrite the MP version's `redun_ids.extend(...)` part to get the timing same as non-MP version?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import multiprocessing as mproc
import sys
import numpy as np
import random
import time

def matdist(mats):
        mat1 = mats[0]
        mat2 = mats[1]
        return np.allclose(mat1, mat2, rtol=1e-08, atol=1e-12)

def mp_remove_redundancy(larrays):
        """
        remove_redundancy : identify arrays that are redundant in the
        input list of arrays
        """
        llen = len(larrays)
        redun_ids = list()
        templist = list()
        i = 0
        **pool = mproc.Pool(processes=10)**
        st1=time.time()
        while 1:
                currarray = larrays[i]
                if i not in redun_ids:
                        templist.append(currarray)
                        #replication to create list of arrays
                        templist = templist*(llen-i-1)
                        **chunksize = len(templist)/10
                        if chunksize == 0:
                                chunksize = 1**
                        #clslist is a result object here
                        st=time.time()
                        **clslist = pool.map_async(matdist, zip(larrays[i+1:],
                                templist), chunksize)**
                        print 'map time:', time.time()-st
                        **outlist = clslist.get()[:]**
                        #j+1+i gives the actual id num w.r.t to whole list
                        st=time.time()
                        redun_ids.extend([j+1+i for j, x in
                                enumerate(outlist) if x])
                        print 'Redun ids extend time:', time.time()-st
                i = i + 1
                del templist[:]
                del outlist[:]
                if i == (llen - 1):
                        break
        print 'Time elapsed in MP:', time.time()-st1
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        del clslist
        del templist
        return redun_ids[:]
#######################################################
def remove_redundancy(larrays):
        llen = len(larrays)
        redun_ids = list()
        clslist = list()
        templist = list()
        i = 0
        st1=time.time()
        while 1:
                currarray = larrays[i]
                if i not in redun_ids:
                        templist.append(currarray)
                        templist = templist*(llen-i-1)
                        st = time.time()
                        clslist = map(matdist, zip(larrays[i+1:],
                                templist))
                        print 'map time:', time.time()-st
                        #j+1+i gives the actual id num w.r.t to whole list
                        st=time.time()
                        redun_ids.extend([j+1+i for j, x in
                                enumerate(clslist) if x])
                        print 'Redun ids extend time:', time.time()-st
                i = i + 1
                #clear temp vars
                del clslist[:]
                del templist[:]
                if i == (llen - 1):
                        break
        print 'Tot non MP time:', time.time()-st1
        del clslist
        del templist
        return redun_ids[:]
###################################################################

if __name__=='__main__':
        if len(sys.argv) != 2:
                sys.exit('# entries')
        llen = int(sys.argv[1])
        #generate random numbers between 1 and 10
        mylist=[np.array([round(random.random()*9+1)]) for i in range(llen)]
        print 'The input list'
        print 'no MP'
        rrlist = remove_redundancy(mylist)
        print 'MP'
        rrmplist = mp_remove_redundancy(mylist)
        print 'Two lists match : {0}'.format(rrlist==rrmplist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite normal that you get a worse performance in the "fan-in" region in an MP scenario, since you're going to incur into communication costs, given that I don't think `multiprocessing` does shared-memory.

In the "fan-out" phase (i.e. call to `map_async`) the parent process needs to serialize the numpy arrays and send them to the children processes (I think via Unix-domain pipes), which have to deserialize them before begin able to use them.

Viceversa, in the "fan-in" phase the children serialize and send, while the parent receives and deserializes, before being able to call `extend` to put them together.

What I'm not entirely sure is why you are detecting a higher time spent in the call to `extend` itself, when I would really expect the bottleneck to be in the call to `get()`. But, again, I don't have enough information to dig any deeper. For example: does `get()` return the deserialized numpy array, or just a proxy that gets lazily computed during the call to `extend`?

And then, again, what timings are we talking about? If we're talking about few milliseconds you should be aware that Python's `time.time()` is not as accurate as you would expect if coming from a C/C++ world. Within that time range, in the Python world, there are so many things happening on the interpreter side that it is really difficult to make a clear meaning out of such small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`clslist = pool.map_async(...)` is very fast because it only sends the requests. If you want to time the whole map operation, include `clslist.get()`, which waits for the results.

Comment: I think this explains the doubts I expressed in my own answer. :)